# Poisson Process proof that

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, proof-writing, self-learning

> For a Poisson process show, for $s<t$ that
>   $$P(N(s)=k\mid N(t)=n)={n\choose
>  k}\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)^{n-k},\space
> > k=0,1,\dots,n$$

I tried a few things but I could not prove

$$P(N(s)=k\mid N(t)=n)=\frac{P(N(s)=k\cap N(t)=n)}{P(N(t)=n)}$$
since $s<t$ I did $N(t)=N(t-s)+N(s)$
$$P(N(s)=k\mid N(t)=n)=\frac{P(N(s)=k\cap N(t-s)+N(s)=n)}{P(N(t)=n)}$$
$$=\frac{P(N(s)=k\cap N(s)=n-N(t-s))}{P(N(t)=n)}=\frac{P(N(t-s)=n-k)}{P(N(t)=n)}$$

I know that $N(t-s)>0\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda(t-s))$ and $N(t)\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t)$

$$P(N(s)=k\mid N(t)=n)=\frac{e^{-\lambda(t-s)}(\lambda(t-s))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{n!}{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}$$

that's what I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N(t)$ is not equal to $N(t-s)+N(s)$, but
$$
N(t) = \Big(N(t) - N(s)\Big) + \Big(N(s)\Big)
$$
and the two expressions inside the $\Big(\text{big parentheses}\Big)$ are independent of each other (whereas $N(t-s)$ and $N(s)$ are **not** independent of each other).  So
\begin{align}
\Pr(N(s) = k \mid N(t) = n) & = \frac{\Pr(N(s)=k\ \&\ N(t) =n) }{\Pr(N(t)=n)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\Pr(N(s)=k\ \&\ N(t)-N(s) = n-k)}{\Pr(N(t)=n)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\Pr(N(s)=k)\Pr(N(t)-N(s) = n-k)}{\Pr(N(t)=n)}.
\end{align}
The last line is where independence is used.  If you find these three probabilities then routine simplifications will do the rest.

Notice that the answer is the same regardless of the value of $\lambda$. The lack of dependence on $\lambda$ means the conditional distribution of arrival times before $t$, given the value of $N(t)$ does not depend on $\lambda$.  Since their distribution does not depend on $\lambda$, those arrival times are irrelevant to the problem of estimating $\lambda$ given then data, once $N(t)$ has been taken into account.  In other words, *all* information about arrival times relevant to estimation of $\lambda$ is contained in $N(t)$, **provided** you can be certain that it's a Poisson process with a constant rate.  But that arrival time data might contain information that could reasonably make you suspect that it does not follow such a model.

Comment: $N(t-s)\neq N(t)-N(s)$? or $N(t-s)\sim Poisson(\lambda(t-s))$ and $N(t)-N(s)\sim Poisson(\lambda(t-s))$?

Comment: $N(t-s)$ and $N(t)-N(s)$ both have the same distribution, which is $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda(t-s))$, but they're not the same thing.  $N(t-s)$ is the number of arrivals between time $0$ and time $t-s$, and $N(t)-N(s)$ is the number of arrivals between time $s$ and time $t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you, I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

By Bayes,$$P(N(s)=k\mid N(t)=n)=P(N(t)=n\mid N(s)=k)\frac{P(N(s)=k)}{P(N(t)=n)}$$Your identity gives:$$=P(N(t-s)=n-k)\frac{P(N(s)=k)}{P(N(t)=n)}$$Sub in Poisson distributions, rest is algebra:$$=e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\frac{(\lambda(t-s))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{e^{-\lambda s}(\lambda s)^k n!}{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n k!}\\={n \choose k}\frac{(t-s)^{n-k}s^k}{t^n}\\={n \choose k}\frac{s^k}{t^k}\frac{(t-s)^{n-k}}{t^{n-k}}$$

Comment: Caveat: I've only used the information in your question, which Michael takes issue with. If some of your information is incorrect, then so is this argument.